# Error while generate reports "Unsupported or unrecognised SQL Server version: 10.50.1600"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, redgate

While creating the reports for remote data using SQL Dependency Tracker. It showing error that

```
"Unsupported or unrecognised SQL Server version: 10.50.1600"
```

Can any help why it's happening how can I solve it?

Comment: Can any one help me please.till now i didn't find any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer would be to update Dependency Tracker. I'm not sure if the version you are using supports SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: ya i checked that i am using latest version 2.7.4.1 and it working fine with local database but problem with remote database